# Simulate a deadlock using stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, deadlock, sybase

Does anyone know how to simulate a deadlock using a stored procedure inserting or updating values? I could only do so in sybase using individual commands.

Thanks,
Ver

Answer (score 3):

Create two stored procedures.

The first should start a transaction, modify table 1 (and take a long time) and then modify table 2.

The second should start a transaction, modify table 2 (and take a long time) and then modify table 1.

Ideally, the modifications should affect the same rows, or create table locks.

Then, in a client application, start SP1, and immediately then also start SP2 (before SP1 has finished).

Answer (score 1):

The simple and short answer to get a deadlock will be to access the tables data in a reverse order and hence introducing a cyclic deadlock between two connections. Let me show you code:

```
Create table vin_deadlock (id int, Name Varchar(30)) 
GO 

Insert into vin_deadlock values (1, 'Vinod') 
Insert into vin_deadlock values (2, 'Kumar') 
Insert into vin_deadlock values (3, 'Saravana') 
Insert into vin_deadlock values (4, 'Srinivas') 
Insert into vin_deadlock values (5, 'Sampath') 
Insert into vin_deadlock values (6, 'Manoj') 
GO
```

Now with the tables ready. Just update the columns in the reverse order from two connections like:

```
-- Connection 1
Begin Tran 
Update vin_deadlock 
SET Name = 'Manoj' 
Where id = 6 
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' 
Update vin_deadlock 
SET Name = 'Vinod' 
Where id = 1
and from connection 2

-- Connection 2
Begin Tran
Update vin_deadlock 
SET Name = 'Vinod' 
Where id = 1 
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' 
Update vin_deadlock 
SET Name = 'Manoj' 
Where id = 6
```

And this will result in a deadlock. You can see the deadlock graph from profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Start a process which continously insert or update a table using while loop with script and run your desired sp.